# using eval() with cython to parse math library functions

Tags: python, eval, cython

I woult like to apply an user defined function to an array of values.
In pure python, importin math library and using eval() worked perfectly, and any math functions like math.sin could be parsed.

With Cython, however, only simple expressions like x*y can be parsed.
For example while parsing:

```
math.sin(x+y)
```

Following error appears:

```
  NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

My code:

```
def evaluate(func,x,y):
    cdef float value
    value = eval(func, locals())                
return value
```

Seems like no imported library functions can be used with eval() function.
Using import * does not solve the problem. Do you know any possible solutions?

Comment: 1. It's generally a bad idea to use `eval()` on user input, since it executes arbitrary code.  2. Please show your code – we can't answer this question without more context.

Comment: here it is. Is there any other flexible way of parsing mathematical functions?

Comment: You are passing the function's local variables as the global scope to the `eval()` function.  The local scope doesn't include `math`, so it's no surprise it isn't found.  Regarding what other options there are – use the `ast` module for parsing, and then walk the AST yourself for evaluation.

Comment: `math` either needs to be in your globals/locals, or you must pass a custom globals/locals parameter to `eval()` (see `help(eval)`)